# Google MAP URL Parameters to draw polyline

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to draw a polyline on google map using its URL parameters?
I know we can draw points on map but what about lines?
for example this URL zooms into a location

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.8757057,0.5278316&z=18&t=k
```

I want something that I can add to Google maps URL and draw a line on map.Is it even possible?

Comment: Please,define with tag on that platform work

Comment: @DavidHackro thank,I don't use any platform.I want a simple URL which could be opened on browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be you can use  staticmap where size is for the dimension and path is a collection of coord  separated  by `|` char

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&sensor=false
```

Comment: thanks,Is this the only way?because it just generate an image not a zoomable map

Comment: This is with static maps  . and this is the only based on a simple (static) url .. otherwise  you should use google api and javascript .. but not an url